# plot array from command line into graph through python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two arrays that are input via command line.  For instance I have the program testarray.py

Now when I enter the command line

```
python testarray.py "1 2 3 4 5 6" "1 2 4 8 16 32"
```

I am trying to get a plot that looks like the following:

[image: Desired Plot]

Unfortunately I am not getting this plot.  I have a linear plot where the y axis is not linear.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
xarr=np.array([])
yarr=np.array([])
zarr=np.array([])

x=sys.argv[1].split(' ')
y=sys.argv[2].split(' ')
length=len(x)

for t in range(0,length):
  xarr = np.append(xarr,x[t])
  yarr = np.append(yarr,y[t])
plt.plot(xarr,yarr,'b')
```

How do I tweak this code to get the desired result?

Comment: _Unfortunately I am not getting this plot._ What are you getting instead? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works. Before you plot, you must convert the numbers that are of type string to integer.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=sys.argv[1].split(' ')
    y=sys.argv[2].split(' ')
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] = int(x[i])
        y[i] = int(y[i])
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

**Update**
With the use of map you can make the whole thing even more elegant.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=list(map(int, sys.argv[1].split(' ')))
    y=list(map(int, sys.argv[2].split(' ')))

    plt.plot(x,y,'b')
    plt.show()
```